# How can I remove all these holes in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, graphics-editing

I’ve been trying to make this vector-like image and there’s all these little bubbles in the image. If you zoom in on the black part of the image, there are a lot of little holes. Is there any simple way I could remove them?

[image: Overview of the image.]

Closeup on the 'holes':

[image: Closeup of the “bubble.”]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to actually convert it to a vector image. Using [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/), follow these steps:

1. Create a new Inkscape document.
2. Select `File` -> `Import` and select your current file (just link to it when asked).
3. Resize the document to fit it:

   1. Open the document properties <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
   2. Click the `Resize Document to Contents` button.
4. Trace the bitmap image with the correct amount of precision to eliminate the speckles.

   1. Open the trace dialog: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
   2. Select `Grays` under `Multiple Scans` on the Trace Bitmap dialog. Use 2 for the color and scan count (although I'm not certain the later matters).
   3. In the options tab of that same dialog make sure that all options are selected and the values read `10, 1.00, 1.00` down the column.
5. Press OK once everything looks good.
6. At this point, you can remove the original PNG link that was imported into the file.
7. If you'd rather have this be PNG format, just export it as a PNG again.

The finished PNG (although, if it were me, I'd just follow the steps above to get it into SVG format and use InkScape to edit it):

[image: Fixed PNG]